# Adding footer / header to PDF via onEndPage using Coldfusion and iText

Tags: coldfusion, itext, pdf-generation

I'm using using ColdFusion and iText to generate PDF documents, and I want to be able to add a header and a footer to a PDF "automatically" whenever iText decides to make a page break.
I've seen examples of how to do this in Java, and here is the basic way to do that:

```
public class MyHeaderFooterPageEvent extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        //add your content here
    }
}
```

And then, before you start composing your PDF document, you "register" your event like his:

```
    MyHeaderFooterPageEvent event = new HeaderFooterPageEvent();
    writer.setPageEvent(event);
```

(At least as far as I understands it.)

I've successfully managed to load the class PdfPageEventHelper into ColdFusion, so I know it's there:

```
<cfset local.PdfPageEventHelper=CreateObject("java","com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper")>
```

And when I dump local.PdfPageEventHelper i get:

[image]

So how do I tell ColdFusion what to do when the onEndPage is called, and how do I register the event so it will be called?

I'm using Coldfusion 11 on a Linux server.

Comment: Imagine how it must feel to see your own name in a dump. That's how I feel when I look at your question, because my name is in there. What does that mean? It means you're using a version of iText that dates at least from 2009. That's 9 years ago. That version is no longer supported. Chances at getting an answer are very low.

Comment: I'm sorry. That is what Coldfusion 11 is shipped with I believe.

Comment: Since you're a ColdFusion customer, have you asked Adobe for support?

Comment: No I haven’t because I don’t think they give support on iText. They would probably refer to the <cfpdf> tag that you can use for more simple PDF generation. That tag is using your library ”under the hood”, obviously.

Comment: I've been Googling for Paul Hastings from sustainablegis.com, but that site doesn't seem to exist anymore. If anyone can help you, it's definitely Paul, but I can't find him anymore. I found someone with the name @paul-hastings on Stack Overflow, but I don't know if that's the same person, and if he is, he hasn't been on Stack Overflow since 2015...

Comment: are you using cfdocument to generate the pdf?

Comment: No, I'm using iText by creating a lot of Objects in cfscript, then finally creating the PDF writer instance via writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(Document, FileOutputStream);

Comment: @JörgenLundgren - If you look at the source, PdfPageEventHelper is meant to be extended. All the methods are empty. You're supposed to create a custom java class and add whatever custom code is needed. Luckily there's an interface involved. So if you don't want to write a java class, instead you can create a CFC that implements the `PdfPageEvent` interface and use createDynamicProxy .   https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/enhanced-java-integration-in-coldfusion.html

Comment: Thank you @Ageax, that seems to be the way to go! Yes I think there is an interface involved. I will look into that and let you know how I did

Comment: The answer is all here in a post from 2009: http://cfsearching.blogspot.se/2009/11/better-itext-pdfpageeventhandler-with.html
Since then ColdFusion 10 has been released, and I have now successfully solved the issue with the newer approach (thanks to @Ageax) by using the CF function CreateDynamicProxy - https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/CreateDynamicProxy.html
I will post pack a full example once I have one.

Comment: (Update) Great! That'll be helpful to others. If you're comfortable with cfscript, I'd use that instead of cfml. The similarities to java syntax make translations easier.

Comment: Good Point. I'll do as much cfscript I can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is mainly based on [this 
 old blog post at cfSearching.blogspot.se](http://cfsearching.blogspot.se/2009/11/better-itext-pdfpageeventhandler-with.html).

While that solution uses the *javaloader dynamic proxy library*, this solution uses the newer(?) function [CreateDynamicProxy](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/CreateDynamicProxy.html) (available from ColdFusion 10 I think), which **Ageax** (many thanks!) made me aware of.

This has been successfully tested in **ColdFusion 11 on a Linux server**.

**To try it yourself:**

1. Copy and paste the content below into one cfm file and one cfc file. While you can name the cfm file whatever you want, the cfc file must be named *PdfPageEventHandler.cfc* in order for this code to work.
2. Put the files in the same folder in a www root on you ColdFusion server.
3. Run the code by surfing to the cfm-file.
4. The browser should display a PDF of 3 pages with body text and footers.

**content of the cfm-file:**

```
<!---call function--->
<cfset _createPdf()>
<!---function for creating pdf with footer that is created via an event handler in onEndPage--->
<cffunction name="_createPdf" output="no" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="pdfFile" type="string" default="document.pdf" hint="the file name to write to disc">
    <cfargument name="writeToBrowser" type="boolean" default="true" hint="will open the pdf document in the browser and delete the file when done">
    <cfscript>
        //set filePath for document
        local.filePath = ExpandPath('.')&"/"&arguments.pdfFile;
        //get BaseFont
        local.BaseFont = CreateObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont");
        //get CMYK color
        local.CMYKColor = CreateObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.CMYKColor");
        //create color
        local.color = local.CMYKColor.init(JavaCast("int",0),JavaCast("int",0),JavaCast("int",0),JavaCast("int",256));
        //create font
        local.font = local.BaseFont.createFont(local.BaseFont.COURIER, local.BaseFont.CP1252, true);
        //compose custom config to make accessable in PdfPageEventHandler.cfc
        local.config = {myCustomFooter = {text = "Page number", color = local.color, font = local.font, size = 20}};
        //init the event handler (make sure the PdfPageEventHandler.cfc is present in the same folder as this template)
        local.eventHandler = CreateObject("component", "PdfPageEventHandler").init(config = local.config); 
        //we can pass in an array of strings which name all the interfaces we want out dynamic proxy to implement
        local.interfaces = ["com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPageEvent"];
        //create a dynamic proxy that we will pass to the iText writer
        local.eventHandlerProxy = CreateDynamicProxy(local.eventHandler, local.interfaces);
        //init success flag
        local.success = true;
        try {
            //init document
            local.document = CreateObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.Document").init();
            //init outstream
            local.outputStream = CreateObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init(local.filePath);
            //init writer
            local.writer = CreateObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter").getInstance(local.document, local.outputStream);
            //register the PROXY as the page event handler
            local.writer.setPageEvent(local.eventHandlerProxy);
            //open document
            local.document.open();
            //init paragraph
            local.paragraph = CreateObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.Paragraph");
            //output some pages with a simple text message. NOTE that our eventHandler will take care of adding footers on every page - that's the whole point with this example by the way :)
            for (local.i = 1; local.i lte 3; local.i = local.i + 1) {
                //add paragraph with text
                local.document.add(local.paragraph.init("This page should have a footer with a page number on it!"));
                //trigger new page
                local.document.newPage();
            }
        } catch (any e) {
            //an error occured
            WriteOutput("Error: " & e.message);
            //set success flag to false
            local.success = false;
        }
        if (StructKeyExists(local, "document")) {
            //close document
            local.document.close();
        }
        if (StructKeyExists(local, "outStream")) {
            //close outStream
            local.outputStream.close();
        }
        if (local.success && arguments.writeToBrowser) {
            _openPdf(filePath=local.filePath);
        }
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
<!---function for opening pdf in browser--->
<cffunction name="_openPdf" output="no" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="filePath" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="#arguments.filePath#" deletefile="yes">
</cffunction>
```

**Content of the cfc file, that should be named *PdfPageEventHandler.cfc***:

```
<cfcomponent output="false" hint="iText Event handler used to add headers, footers, etc.">
<!---1. INIT FUNCTION--->
    <cffunction name="init" access="public" returntype="PdfPageEventHandler" output="false">
        <!---come up with your own arguments that you want to have access to in onEndPage etc--->
        <cfargument name="config" type="any" required="true" hint="custom config" />
        <!---make sure the config is accessable by other functions--->
        <cfset variables.config = arguments.config>
        <cfreturn this />
    </cffunction>
<!---2. ON END PAGE - the function that is in focus in this example--->
    <cffunction name="onEndPage" access="public" returntype="void" output="true" hint="Called when a page is finished, just before being written to the document.">
        <cfargument name="writer" type="any" required="true" hint="Writer for the target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter" />
        <cfargument name="document" type="any" required="true" hint="Document for target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Document" />
        <!---edit below to make your own header / footer--->
        <cfscript>
            local.cb = arguments.writer.getDirectContent();
            local.cb.saveState();
            local.cb.beginText();
            local.cb.setColorFill(variables.config.myCustomFooter.color);
            local.cb.setFontAndSize(variables.config.myCustomFooter.font, variables.config.myCustomFooter.size);
            local.cb.setTextMatrix(arguments.document.left(), arguments.document.bottom() - 10);
            local.text = "#variables.config.myCustomFooter.text# #arguments.writer.getPageNumber()#";
            local.cb.showText(local.text);
            local.cb.endText();
            local.cb.restoreState();
        </cfscript>
    </cffunction>
<!---3. OTHER FUNCTIONS THAT MUST EXIST (at least in this example)--->
    <cffunction name="onOpenDocument" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="Called when the document is opened.">
        <cfargument name="writer" type="any" required="true" hint="Writer for the target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter" />
        <cfargument name="document" type="any" required="true" hint="Document for target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Document" />
        <!---To be implemented: Code called when the document is opened--->
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="onCloseDocument" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="Called when the document is closed">
        <cfargument name="writer" type="any" required="true" hint="Writer for the target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter" />
        <cfargument name="document" type="any" required="true" hint="Document for target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Document" />
        <!---To be implemented: Code called when the document is closed--->
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="onStartPage" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="Called when a page is initialized.">
        <cfargument name="writer" type="any" required="true" hint="Writer for the target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter" />
        <cfargument name="document" type="any" required="true" hint="Document for target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Document" />
        <!---To be implemented: Code called when a page is initialized--->
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="onParagraph" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="Called when a Paragraph is written">
        <cfargument name="writer" type="any" required="true" hint="Writer for the target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter" />
        <cfargument name="document" type="any" required="true" hint="Document for target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Document" />
        <cfargument name="paragraphPosition" type="numeric" required="true" hint="The position the chapter will be written to. Value is a java float" />
        <!---To be implemented: Code called when paragraph is written --->
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="onParagraphEnd" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="Called when a Paragraph is written">
        <cfargument name="writer" type="any" required="true" hint="Writer for the target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter" />
        <cfargument name="document" type="any" required="true" hint="Document for target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Document" />
        <cfargument name="paragraphPosition" type="numeric" required="true" hint="The position the chapter will be written to. Value is a java float" />
        <!---To be implemented: Code called on end of paragraph is written--->
    </cffunction>
<!---4. FUNCTIONS THAT ONLY NEEDS TO EXIST IF YOU DO SOMETHING THAT TRIGGERS THEM
    <cffunction name="OnChapter" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="Called when a Chapter is written">
        <cfargument name="writer" type="any" required="true" hint="Writer for the target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter" />
        <cfargument name="document" type="any" required="true" hint="Document for target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Document" />
        <cfargument name="paragraphPosition" type="numeric" required="true" hint="The position the chapter will be written to. Value is a java float" />
        <cfargument name="title" type="any" required="true" hint="Title of the chapter. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Paragraph" />
        <!---To be implemented: Code called when a Chapter is written--->
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="onChapterEnd" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="Called when the end of a Chapter is reached">
        <cfargument name="writer" type="any" required="true" hint="Writer for the target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter" />
        <cfargument name="document" type="any" required="true" hint="Document for target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Document" />
        <cfargument name="position" type="numeric" required="true" hint="The position of the end of the chapter. Value is a java float" />
        <!---To be implemented: Code called when the end of a Chapter is reached--->
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="onGenericTag" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="Called when a Chunk with a generic tag is written">
        <cfargument name="writer" type="any" required="true" hint="Writer for the target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter" />
        <cfargument name="document" type="any" required="true" hint="Document for target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Document" />
        <cfargument name="rect" type="any" required="true" hint="The Rectangle containing the Chunk. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Rectangle" />
        <cfargument name="text" type="string" required="true" hint="The text of the tag" />
        <!---To be implemented: Code called when a Chunk with a generic tag is written--->
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="onSection" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="Called when a Section is written">
        <cfargument name="writer" type="any" required="true" hint="Writer for the target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter" />
        <cfargument name="document" type="any" required="true" hint="Document for target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Document" />
        <cfargument name="paragraphPosition" type="numeric" required="true" hint="The position the chapter will be written to. Value is a java float" />
        <cfargument name="depth" type="numeric" required="true" hint="The number depth of the Section. Value is a java int" />
        <cfargument name="title" type="any" required="true" hint="Title of the section. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Paragraph" />
        <!---To be implemented: Code called when a Section is written--->
    </cffunction>
    <cffunction name="onSectionEnd" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="Called when the end of a Section is reached.">
        <cfargument name="writer" type="any" required="true" hint="Writer for the target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter" />
        <cfargument name="document" type="any" required="true" hint="Document for target pdf. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Document" />
        <cfargument name="paragraphPosition" type="numeric" required="true" hint="The position the chapter will be written to. Value is a java float" />
        <cfargument name="depth" type="numeric" required="true" hint="The number depth of the Section. Value is a java int" />
        <cfargument name="title" type="numeric" required="true" hint="Title of the section. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Paragraph" />
        <!---To be implemented: Code called when the end of a Section is reached--->
    </cffunction>
    --->
</cfcomponent>
```

**UPDATE!**

**Here's that same cfc, but in pure cfscript, for you that rather prefer that:**

```
<cfscript>
    component output="false"  hint="iText Event handler used to add headers, footers, etc." {
        property name="config" type="struct";
        //1. INIT FUNCTION
        public PdfPageEventHandler function init(required any config) {
            //make sure the config is accessable by other functions
            variables.config = arguments.config;
            return this;
        }
    //2. ON END PAGE - the function that is in focus in this example
        public void function onEndPage(required any writer, required any document) {
            //Called when a page is finished, just before being written to the document
            //edit below to make your own header / footer
            local.cb = arguments.writer.getDirectContent();
            local.cb.saveState();
            local.cb.beginText();
            local.cb.setColorFill(variables.config.myCustomFooter.color);
            local.cb.setFontAndSize(variables.config.myCustomFooter.font, variables.config.myCustomFooter.size);
            local.cb.setTextMatrix(arguments.document.left(), arguments.document.bottom() - 10);
            local.text = "#variables.config.myCustomFooter.text# #arguments.writer.getPageNumber()#";
            local.cb.showText(local.text);
            local.cb.endText();
            local.cb.restoreState();
        }
    //3. OTHER FUNCTIONS THAT MUST EXIST (at least in this example)
        public void function onOpenDocument(required any writer, required any document) {
            //Called when the document is opened
        }
        public void function onCloseDocument(required any writer, required any document) {
            //Called when the document is closed
        }
        public void function onStartPage(required any writer, required any document) {
            //Called when a page is initialized
        }
        public void function onParagraph(required any writer, required any document, required numeric paragraphPosition) {
            //Called when a Paragraph is written
            //paragraphPosition - The position the chapter will be written to. Value is a java float
        }
        public void function onParagraphEnd(required any writer, required any document, required numeric paragraphPosition) {
            //Called when a Paragraph is written
            //paragraphPosition - The position the chapter will be written to. Value is a java float
        }
    //4. FUNCTIONS THAT ONLY NEEDS TO EXIST IF YOU DO SOMETHING THAT TRIGGERS THEM
        public void function OnChapter(required any writer, required any document, required numeric paragraphPosition, required any title) {
            //Called when a Chapter is written
            //paragraphPosition - The position the chapter will be written to. Value is a java float
            //title - Title of the chapter. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Paragraph
        }
        public void function onChapterEnd(required any writer, required any document, required numeric position) {
            //Called when the end of a Chapter is reached
            //position - The position of the end of the chapter. Value is a java float
        }
        public void function onGenericTag(required any writer, required any document, required any rect, required string text) {
            //Called when a Chunk with a generic tag is written
            //rect - The Rectangle containing the Chunk. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Rectangle
            //text - The text of the tag
        }
        public void function onSection(required any writer, required any document, required numeric paragraphPosition, required numeric depth, required any title) {
            //Called when a Section is written
            //paragraphPosition - The position the section will be written to. Value is a java float
            //depth - The number depth of the Section. Value is a java int
            //title - Title of the section. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Paragraph
        }
        public void function onSectionEnd(required any writer, required any document, required numeric paragraphPosition, required numeric depth, required any title) {
            //Called when the end of a Section is reached
            //paragraphPosition - The position the section will be written to. Value is a java float
            //depth - The number depth of the Section. Value is a java int
            //title - Title of the section. Instance of com.lowagie.text.Paragraph
        }
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Nicely done!  Works a charm.  For even greater flexibility, you could also have the function accept arguments: `fileName` (default of "doc_#createUUID()#.pdf") and `deleteFile` (true/false). That would allow overriding the default file name and auto cleanup of the temp file.

Comment: Thanks! Glad it worked for you too. Good Idea. I’ve changed it to a constant file name now. I wasn’t gonna let some browser caching of my pdf document make me tear my hair :) That’s why I used a unique file name every time.

Comment: (Update) Actually, your first idea was perfect :) Using a unique name also helps with thread safety. Using a uuid means there's no i/o conflict if multiple threads generate the same file name at the same time. You can always add a `cfheader` if you want to display a different file name in the browser. Though, I'd make the file related settings arguments in *both* functions. Then changing on the fly is easy. Just pass in a different value.

Comment: I tried the cfheader approach with unique filename, but then the browser downloaded the file instead (tried both the inline and attachment approach) - possibly due to some browser settings. So anyhow, I decided to go with an argument flag of "writeToBrowser" and the deletefile="yes" option in cfcontent to keep it clean during development.

Comment: Weird, I'll have to try it sometime.  Thanks again for posting such a great example.